# Having problems with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, sfml, visual-studio-2019

So I am trying to get started with SFML and game making in C++ but I can't even start the basic "Hello World" program. When I press F5 it prints out "ops.Press any key to close this window . . .". Here is the only information that I get from the debug window bellow.

```
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\VisualStudio\Projects\SFML\Debug\SFML.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0xbe8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'SFML.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. 
The thread 0x2194 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x28d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x179c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[13688] SFML.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Also I don't know why are those .dll files loading since i used them in a previous project that I deleted. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use might have included some sfml libraries under your project settings.

Comment: I'v deleted all those libraries from the linker properties. I don't know why is Visual Studio still loading them every time I press F5

Comment: Is this a fresh project or is it one you had SFML stuff in before? You might need to clean and rebuild from the build menu.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a problem to begin with? The debug log is what you'll see for a successful run of a program. Note in particular all the thread exit codes are 0 (meaning success). Without seeing your code, or even a description of what you expect, there's no help to be had. Read [ask].